# How to convert date into integer number in php?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have an mysql database with a date column and i am using datatype datetime.

But now i want change my datatype from datetime to long integer

I would like to know how to convert date to any integer value.

Let say i have a date

i.e `2012-03-27 18:47:00`

so I was wondering if it's possible to convert into  any integer number like `131221154`

Comment: yes i am using php for converting this.

Comment: That's a datetime , you need to think about what you are doing here. Why do you want a long?

Comment: Is their any solution for converting text into integer number?

Answer (score 38):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) function of PHP.

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

```
echo strtotime('2012-03-27 18:47:00'); //--> which results to 1332866820
```

And to make it back again, just use the [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of PHP:

```
$long = strtotime('2012-03-27 18:47:00'); //--> which results to 1332866820
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $long);
```

Comment: What about `strtotime("1900-06-12")`

Comment: For 64-bit versions of PHP, date prior to January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC will return a negative timestamp. Otherwise it may return a bool false, depend on which platform you're using.

Answer (score 11):

check this

```
<?php
$timestamp = strtotime('1st January 2004'); //1072915200

// this prints the year in a two digit format
// however, as this would start with a "0", it
// only prints "4"
echo idate('y', $timestamp);
?>
```